# Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces when publishing to GCP PubSub using pubsub.v1.Publisher

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

GCP Cloud Function will publish a message successfully but throws a warning messages as follow:

```
[ault-executor-0] i.g.n.s.i.n.u.internal.MacAddressUtil: Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes:
```

apparently caused by

```
 private final Publisher publisher;

 private void some_method(){
    publisher.publish(message).get();
 }
```

where `Publisher` is `com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher` from

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
      <version>1.112.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

What can cause such of warning? CloudFunction, PubSub, or the GCP project configuration?

Comment: Can you share the piece of code that cause that?

Comment: Networking is virtualized in Google Cloud. The physical MAC layer is not required. Do not deploy code that requires those details. This [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/advanced-vpc) will provide more details. `MAC lookup table, IP lookup table, active connection table These tables are hosted on the underlying VPC network and cannot be inspected or configured.`

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere OP updated

Comment: @JohnHanley please read the updated OP. It is caused by `com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher`, not my code, and it looks like Netty inside that dependency as the full log header is `[ault-executor-0] i.g.n.s.i.n.u.internal.MacAddressUtil`

Comment: Have you tried a newer version for your artifact?